# reminescent hankering of a past event

Tags: idioms

Is there a single word or idiom for a reminescent hankering for a past event - such as a concert, a party, a vacation, etc. attended with friends or whoever company?

Comment: Been answered on here a few times.  Nostalgic, good old days, sentimental.

Comment: I am looking for a possible, single, verb form or an idiomatic phrase in a verb construction of it sir.

Answer (score 5):

Nostalgia, from the Greek *nostos, homecoming,* and *algos, pain.*

Answer (score 0):

Consider *saudade*.

> [saudade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saudade): a feeling of longing, melancholy, or nostalgia that is supposedly characteristic of the Portuguese or Brazilian temperament.

In the way of verbs, *pine* might fit what you're looking for.

> [pine](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/long): to have a languishing or fruitless longing for what is impossible : *All of a sudden, I [pined for](http://www.larmoireessentielle.com/2013_06_01_archive.html) the carefree days of my youth...*

Answer (score 0):

*To long* might work, as in "He longed for the carefree days of his youth," or "She entered her eighth decade with a sharp longing for the days when people had to go to the library to have their obscure language questions answered instead of hopping onto Stack Exchange for quick answers."